# GRPC from client to server with forward proxy in node.js

Tags: node.js, proxy, grpc

I' trying to make a gRPC connection behind a proxy on the internet from a node.js app.
I can't find documentation that describes how to configure the gRPC module to use a forward proxy.

Answer (score 0):

When running gRPC, you can specify an http_proxy environment variable.

See
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md